# Spark Read JSON with Request Parameters

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read a JSON response from [IBM Cloud's DB2 Warehouse documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/db2-warehouse-on-cloud#request-a-new-access-token). This requires me to pass a request body wherein I have to supply `userid` and `password` as request parameters.

To read using `spark.read.json`, I did not find anything wherein request parameters could be supplied. Is there anyway using which we could do that?

Usually I would read the JSON using Scala alone using `scalaj-http` and `play-json` libraries like:

```
val body = Json.obj(Constants.KEY_USERID -> userid, Constants.KEY_PASSWORD -> password)

val response = Json.parse(Http(url + Constants.KEY_ENDPOINT_AUTH_TOKENS)
    .header(Constants.KEY_CONTENT_TYPE , "application/json") 
    .header(Constants.KEY_ACCEPT , "application/json")   
    .postData(body.toString())  
    .asString.body)
```

My requirement is I cannot use these 2 libraries and have to do it using `scala` with the `spark` framework.

Comment: Try to take a look on jdbc connector for DB2 https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2017/05/20/working-bigsql-data-spark-shell-using-spark-jdbc-connector/. It allows to pass username and password with options.

Comment: I'm not looking to connect via JDBC. My use case requires me to use the REST API and the authentication token that comes out of it.. To pass the credentials, I need to send them as a header (like it is usually done when using `POST` request) but I did not find any resources on the internet which help passing headers while calling `spark.read.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `spark.read.json` directly for REST API data ingestion.

First, make your API call request to get response data and then convert it to DataFrame with Spark. Note that if your API is paginated then, you'll need to make multiple calls to get all data.

For your example, you need to call authentication endpoint in order to get a `Bearer token` and then add it to the request header :

```
Authorization: Bearer <your_token>
```

All this part could be done using only Scala (example `scala.io.Source.fromURL`).

Once you get the `response_data`, use spark to convert it to DF :

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(response_data).toDS)
```